# Tall vs Wide Hbase Table design

Tags: hbase, mapr

We have below usecase and want to find out what would be the general suggestion for the design of Table MaprDB/HBase.

Our data consists of users(say unique username) and count(integer values per hour)
We have 10K-100K requests to update db for every 10secs. We have to store 8000 hours of data to be stored for every user.
I tried creating single row with rowkey as username and 1 "count" column with 8000 versions. But I could not "Increment" a particular version depending on the hour of data that is coming in(Hbase "Increment" Api doesn't support "timestamp" parameter unlike "Put"). I tried creating a KeyValue with specific timestamp for this row and column, but it only updates the latest version.

So, now I have to redesign this. This is where I need the suggestion. Is it a better idea to create a Tall table with row key as "username + hour" and have only one column for the count and use Increment to update that one column or make the table Wide where i have row key as username and 8000 columns. Please note that I will be querying this table lets say once every 30mins and cache the data. This is a write heavy table.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

we had almost similar issue. Our data model is somewhere between thin/tall and thick/short.